# How to set Asp.Net Core app as a service in Windows 10 IoT Core?

Tags: service, asp.net-core, webserver, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I have successfully deployed an ASP.NET Core 2.0 (MVC) on Win IoT Core (running on Rasp Pi 3). The device is listening on 192.168.0.14:80.

[image]

I activate the application via PowerShell (from my host computer connected to the device) as follows.

[image]

The problem is that if I close the PowerShell window, the server stop listening.

## Question

How to active the web application as a service that is always running even after restarting the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try connectin to the RPi:

`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <Raspberry IP> -Credential <Raspberry IP>\Administrator`

And then schedule a task:

`schtasks /create /tn "Startup Web" /tr c:\Startup.bat /sc onstart /ru SYSTEM`

Where startup.bat executes a powershell script with something like:

`Set-Location C:\publish\ .\aspnet.on.rpi.exe`

Check this post for a complete sample: https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/03/26/raspberry-pi-run-aspnet-core-on-startup/

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem running something like: schtasks /create /tn "Startup Web" /tr c:\publish\aspnet.on.rpi.exe /sc onstart /ru SYSTEM I use the powershell script to run more things and checks at startup.

Comment: If you don't use the batch file the you need to invoke powershell.exe within the schtask command. Something like: schtasks.exe /create /tn "Startup Web" /sc onstart /tr "powershell.exe -file C:\startup.ps1"